# How to bind DataGrid cell text FontWeight to some property in the DataTable cell the grid is binded to?

Tags: wpf, datatable, binding, datagrid

I have tried to do it so, but it does not work as I expect. I am placing objects of some class to one of table columns (of that Type), and trying to get the text bold if the bool property 'bold' is set to 'true'.

some 'item class':

```
public class CellItem {
    public string str { get; set; }
    public bool bold { get; set; }

    public CellItem (string txt, bool bld) {
        str = txt;
        bold = bld;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return str;
    }
}
```

in some DataContext:

```
DataTable _grid_items = new DataTable("table");
public DataView grid_items { get => _grid_items.DefaultView; }
...
_grid_items.Columns.Add(new DataColumn($"column {colnum++}", typeof (CellItem));
_grid_items.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column 1"));
_grid_items.Rows.Add(new CellItem("row 0 col 0", false), "row 0 col 1");
_grid_items.Rows.Add(new CellItem("row 1 col 0", true), "row 1 col 1");
_grid_items.Rows.Add(new CellItem ("row 2 col 0", true), "row 2 col 1");
...
```

and in XAML:

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding grid_items}" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
                          CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200"
                          Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CellItem.bold}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

the question is why the texts "row 1 col 0" & "row 2 col 0" are not bold, and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to properties of custom objects in a `DataTable`.

Replace the `DataTable` with an `IEnumerable<CellItem>`:

```
List<CellItem> _grid_items = new List<CellItem>();
public IEnumerable<CellItem> grid_items { get => _grid_items; }
...
_grid_items.Add(new CellItem("row 0 col 0", true);
...
```

...and bind directly to property in your template:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding bold}" Value="true">
```